# Request from React to my Spring backend fails

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, axios, backend

When i trying to send request via axios with valid Barier token its reponding with
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'protocol')`

I using Spring boot 3 and Spring Security 5 for backend
**Endpoint i want to fetch:**

```
@GetMapping()
public List<User> allUsers() {
    return userRepository.findAll();
}
```

**Axios call:**

```
import axios from "axios";
import config from "../config.json";

const apiEnpoint = config.apiEnpoint; //http://localhost:8080/api/user
const jwtToken =
  "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2ODg2NTk3ODQsImV4cCI6NDY4ODY1OTc4NCwic3ViIjoiRGVuaXMyMyJ9.lwJOQnMfmZkxVXeeC7eOmJ74CjgaEquEr9qtW0TV4PI";

export function getAllUsers() {
  return axios.get(apiEnpoint, {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${jwtToken}` },
  });
}
```

Spring even acting like front application even not try to call it. Filter which validates jwt token even not executing

**Important to mention that all is fine when i try to fetch data using postman.**

I need my front to fetch list of users properly.